# Start array of finding objects at 1

Tags: unity, c#

I have gameObjects that I need to find in my script that are having naming conventions such as "Obj_1", "Obj_2", "Obj_3" and so on. Now I am using an array to find the objects that is given below:

```
public GameObject[] Positions;

void Start()
    {
        for(int j=0; j<Pos.Length; j++)
        {
            {
                Pos[j] = GameObject.Find("Obj_"+j);
            }
            
        }
    }
```

So the problem is `Pos[0] = null` whereas I want `Pos[0] = Obj_1`, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Hint: You want j of 0 to map to 1, j of 1 to map to 2, j of 2 to map to 3, j of 3 to map to 4... can you see a relation here? Also, I don't think your question is a great fit to this site, as it is more of a generic programming question than about game dev.

Comment: Well I tried but I get index out of bounds error. Can you please post a solution? @Tyyppi_77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to write:

```
// Form a name that's Obj_1 when j is 0,
// Obj_2 when j is 1, etc...
string name = "Obj_" + (j + 1);

// Find the object with that name.
Pos[j] = GameObject.Find(name);
```

But honestly I recommend that you never use this code at all. [Looking up game objects by name is brittle and error prone](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/672973048899702784?s=19), and not particularly efficient. There is almost always a better solution to the problem.

In future, try asking about the root problem you want to solve instead. What game feature are you implementing that leads to needing an array of game object references that can't be populated directly as those objects are created, either by the designer at edit time, or by a spawner script at runtime?

It's very likely *something* in your pipeline knows what these objects are without searching for them, so zoom out enough that we can see how they fit into the wider scope of your game's features and we may be able to propose better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I created another variable and incremented it.

```
int i = 1;
for(int j=0; j<Pos.Length && i<Pos.Length+1; j++, i++)
        {
           Pos[j] = GameObject.Find("Obj_"+i);
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to include i in the loop test. j will suffice there.

Comment: but i should be 1 when j = 0.

Comment: Yes, and the loop test `i<Pos.Length+1;` does absolutely nothing to help make that happen.